# React Redux not rendering on state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a map application built using React/Redux.  In this application there is the option to move objects and I am attempting to build in an undo/redo function.  I have keypress handlers in place for the undo which calls the Redux action creator to increment (or decrement) the "currentMove" counter.  My render function pulls the array of items (desks) using `'this.props.layout.deskMoves[this.props.layout.currentDesk]'` This has been extrapolated to a separate function.  The drag function I am using works correctly and moves the desk and then updates the database.  It also updates the 'deskMoves' array.  But when I hit CTRL+Z the 'currentMoves' pointer changes correctly but the desks are not redrawn in the new location.  I cannot figure out where the problem lies as I have checked to be certain that I am not passing array references but rather using the spread operator to create a copy of the array for each move.

Here are my various functions:

```
    handleKeyPress = (e) => {
        if (this.state.edit) {
            switch (e.code) {
                case 'KeyZ':
                    if (e.ctrlKey) this.props.Layout_Undo_Change();
                    e.cancelBubble = true;
                    break;
                case 'KeyY':
                    if (e.ctrlKey) this.props.Layout_Redo_Change();
                    e.cancelBubble = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
export const Layout_Undo_Change = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState();
    let current = state.layout.currentMove;

    if (current > 0)
        current--;

    return dispatch({
        type: ActionTypes.LAYOUT_SET_MOVES,
        payload: current
    });
}
```

```
buildDesks = () => {
        const newScale = this.getScale();
        const layout = this.props.layout;
        const desks = this.getDesks();

        let ret = desks.map((desk, index) => {
            let deskImg = null;
            try {
                let dImg = layout.deskTypes.find(
                    d => parseInt(d.deskType) === parseInt(desk.deskType)
                );
                deskImg = dImg.deskImage;
            }
            catch (ex) {
                console.log(ex);
            }
            const userName = desk.UserLogon !== (null || '') ? desk.UserLogon : "Unassigned";

            const top = Math.trunc(parseInt(parseInt(desk.y) * newScale));
            const left = Math.trunc(parseInt(parseInt(desk.x) * newScale));

            let imgStyle = {
                width: `${parseInt(parseInt(desk.width) * newScale)}px`,
                height: `${parseInt((parseInt(desk.height) * newScale))}px`,
                transform: `rotate(${parseInt(desk.rotation)}deg)`,
                position: 'absolute'
            }
            if (layout.currentDesk && desk.id === layout.currentDesk.id) {
                imgStyle.border = '2px solid cyan';
            }
            const url = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${deskImg}`;
            try {
                return (
                    <Draggable key={desk.id}
                        index={index}
                        enabled={this.state.edit}
                        left={left}
                        top={top}
                        onMove={this.updateProperties}
                        onStop={this.mouseUp}
                        onRightClick={this.rightClick}
                    >
                        <div style={{ position: 'relative' }} className='deskImg'>
                            <img style={imgStyle} alt={userName} src={url} />
                        </div>
                    </Draggable>
                );
            }
            catch (ex) {
                console.log(ex);
                return null;
            }
        });//desks.map
        return ret;
    }//buildDesks
```

```
render() {
        if (this.props.layout.isLoading) {
            return (<Loading title="Site Layout" />);
        }
        else if (this.props.layout.isLoadingMap) {
            const map = this.props.layout.maps[this.props.layout.currentMap];
            const siteName = map.SiteName;
            return (
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={1}></Col>
                    <Col sm={10} id="Layout_Map_Container">
                        <Loading title={"map '" + siteName + "'"} />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            );
        }
        else if (this.props.layout.mapLoaded) {
            return (
                <div>

                    <Row>
                        <Col sm={1}>
                            {this.showAdmin()}
                        </Col>
                        <Col sm={10}>
                            {this.state.details} {this.props.layout.currentMove}
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col sm={1}>
                            <select onChange={(e) => this.changeMap(e.target)}>
                                {this.buildMapOptions()}
                            </select>
                        </Col>
                        <Col sm={10} id="Layout_Map_Container">
                            {this.buildMap()}
                            {this.buildDesks()}

                        </Col>
                    </Row >
                    {this.showStatus()}
                </div>
            );
        }
        else {
            return (
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={1}>
                        <select onChange={(e) => this.changeMap(e.target)}>
                            {this.buildMapOptions()}
                        </select>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={10} id="Layout_Map_Container">
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Some further information:  When I use CTRL-Z nothing happens until I click on the most recently moved desk.  At that point it jumps to its previous position.  Undoing multiple times has the same effect on every desk I have moved.  If I undo multiple times it will revert each desk only after I click on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually occurring in the event handler in the  component.  Once the dust settled I had extracted this single file into multiple files and treating each individual desk as a separate component with it's own state tracking.  This allowed the undo function to modify the state of each changed desk and also allowed each desk component to modify it's own state, forcing a redraw.  Being a fairly complex page I found that the simplification of extracting every item in it to a separate page allowed for more fine tuning of component events and state.